# What's supposed to happen in the "Something for the Neighbors" quest?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I had a quest from Liam called "Something for the Neighbors" and the only objective was to advance Jaal's Friend or Foe mission. But when I did (by handling things on Eos), Liam's mission went straight into the Completed folder.

Did I miss something? Is there a different progression through the game (an earlier set of Jaal's Friend or Foe objectives, maybe?) that produces an actual quest or at least a cutscene out of this, or is this it?

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly (I did this mission a couple weeks ago), the same thing happened to me but I didn't pay much attention to it. It also turns out that that mission isn't actually in the guide to [Liam's core loyalty missions](http://segmentnext.com/2017/03/23/mass-effect-andromeda-liam-kosta-loyalty-missions-guide/). The ones that are include: Armor Diplomacy, All in, Day out on Aya, Community, and Outpost Worlds (the one that just wants you to settle each possible world).

Initially I came across [a reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/masseffect/comments/62yfo3/mea_spoilers_mission_something_for_the_neighbours/) who assumed the quest was bugged as it seemed to be for you, it just suddenly was marked complete.

However, I came across [this](http://masseffectandromeda.wiki.fextralife.com/Liam+Kosta:+Something+for+Us) (albeit a pretty bare bones wiki), it had a key piece of information that I think is the cause of the mission being set to complete. In order to advance into "Something for the Neighbors" there is a prerequisite of: **"Must be Sarah Ryder and have committed to Liam in the Community mission".**

**So I am presuming you are playing as male Ryder and cannot actually progress this quest-line any further as committing to Liam is not an option as male Ryder. It would normally progress otherwise after completing that portion of Jaal's loyalty quest-line.**

Comment: Hmm. The wiki link is for the "Something for Us" quest. I also *just* got the Community mission. But still, this sounds like a plausible theory.

Comment: Considering that it's a bare wiki, my assumption was the mission was mislabeled. You are male Ryder though?

Comment: There is also this guide here http://guides.gamepressure.com/masseffectandromeda/guide.asp?ID=39165 that also labels the quest as "Something for Us" and is listed in the same way (Only if you are female Ryder and are flirting/romancing with Liam)

Comment: Yeah, male Ryder here. There is another mission called Something for Us. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: Hm. Interesting.. I can't find *anything* concrete on Something for the Neighbors.. Also a chance it's just something to encourage your to complete Jaal's quests before you can progress Liam